# How to check for number of events on agendaDay and basicDay views

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I want to disable the calendar if there are no events for the day (I'm using it on a sidebar in basicDay view).  Does anyone know how I can check for the number of events so I can disable the calendar if there are none?

Help is much appreciated!  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Additionally, I may want to find the next day that contains at least one event and jump to that day.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following callbacks to find out if there is any data in a view:

```
var numEvents = 0;
$("#calendar").fullCalendar({
    loading: function(isLoading, view) {
        if(isLoading) { // starting to fetch events
            numEvents = 0;
        } else { // done fetching events
            if(numEvents == 0) {
                // disable calendar
            } else {
                // ensure calendar is enabled
            }
        }
    },
    eventAfterRender: function(event, element, view) {
        numEvents++;
    }
});
```

Since FullCalendar only loads events for the current view, to figure out which view has new data (unless you store them all on the client side), you'll want to implement code on the server side that can return the next date with an event.  You can then use [gotoDate](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/current_date/gotoDate/) on the calendar to go to that date once you get it from the server.